# logrotate says it's running but it's not

Tags: logrotate

I have just set this box up as a log server so I can forward to a SIEM but the file is not rotating the way I expect.

```
/var/log/remote/*.log {
    daily
    dateext
    rotate 4
    compress
    delaycompress
}
```

If I run

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf -fv
```

logrotate sees that it should rotate the logs

```
considering log /var/log/remote/logstash-prod.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/remote/logstash-prod.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20151009'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding logs to compress failed
glob finding old rotated logs failed
renaming /var/log/remote/logstash-prod.log to      /var/log/remote/logstash-prod.log-20151009
creating new /var/log/remote/logstash-prod.log mode = 0600 uid = 0 gid = 0
```

but never writes logstash-prod.log-20151009

How can I troubleshoot why this is happening?

- I have disk space
- I am running the command as root
- /etc/logrotate.conf is the system supplied copy (AWS Linux 2015.09)

Answer (score 2):

RTFM helps, I assumed -d was to specify the directory containing the config. It's actually debug which is a dry run.